# What is this error: express deprecated res.redirect(url, status): Use res.redirect(status, url)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

All just work fine with this code the only problem is with this redirect route
*res.redirect("/campgrounds/",+ updatedCampground._id);*
I'm trying to find its solution, do anyone knows what it is?

```
    //Edit Routes
    router.get('/:id/edit', function(req, res){
        Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundCampground){
            if (err){
                res .redirect('/campgrounds');
            }else{
                res.render('campgrounds/edit', {campground: foundCampground} )
            }
        })
    });

    router.put('/:id', function(req, res){
        //Find and update the correct campround
        Campground.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.campground, function(err, updatedCampground){
            if (err){
                res.redirect("/campgrounds");
            }else{
                res.redirect("/campgrounds/",+ updatedCampground._id);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code:

```
res.redirect("/campgrounds/",+ updatedCampground._id);
```

Sends two arguments to `res.redirect()`.  The first is the string `"/campgrounds"`.  The second argument (separated by the comma) is `+ updatedCampground._id`.

Probably what you mean is this (where you remove the comma):

```
res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + updatedCampground._id);
```

The error message is telling that if you use two arguments for `res.redirect()`, they have to be `res.redirect(status, url)`, but it looks to Express like you are trying to do `res.redirect(url, status)` which is why it is complaining.  But all of that is caused because of the extra comma that you need to remove so you are sending just one string instead of a string and a number.

Answer (score 1):

Is Express seeing your `redirect` call as having two inputs because of the comma?
`res.redirect("/campgrounds/",+ updatedCampground._id);`

try it without the comma as a single input:
`res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + updatedCampground._id);`